# Request fails for photo upload Phonegap with Forms Authentication

Tags: cookies, ssl, asp.net-web-api, cordova, forms-authentication

We are developing a PhoneGap application where in we have photo upload functionality. If I enable FormsAuthentication in WebApi the photo upload fails. So we found that it was failing because .aspxauth cookie was not a part of request. To solve this we made ajax call to get the .aspxauth cookie

WebAPi Controller Code

```
 public string GetAuthCookie()
        {
            HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            return authCookie.Value.ToString();
        }
```

Phone Gap Code

```
var headers={'.ASPXAUTH':cookievalue};
options.headers = headers;
```

This worked while ssl is not enabled, but when we enable SSL this request fails giving error code "3".
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After giving much more time found that issue was not related to cookie but SSL, phonegap photoupload feature doesn't let you upload photo with self signed certificate or trial certificate to fix that need add true attribute in upload method

ft.upload(fileuri, encodeURI(PublishUrl+"FileUpload"), win, fail, options,true);